# Monitoring threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an app that spawns multiple threads. Each thread has quite complex logic. Sometimes there is a deadlock or other problem and I would like to be informed that Thread is not in a "healthy" state anymore.

Options that come to my mind:

1. Log and monitor logs
2. Update shared object in memory from each thread (for example dictionary with thread id as a key and status structure: OK, timespan and then in separate thread observe that dictionary and if thread hasn't updated it's status for X minutes then it means that something went wrong)

But I have a feeling that it isn't the best solution. Is there any pother good practice for monitoring threads? Maybe thread itself can update it's global state with timestamp and process has access to that information?

Comment: Maybe this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: the answer to the question is anything you can do to debug whats going on will help, whether its logs or debugging ect ect. But as to anything else we cant really help you

Comment: There is a thread window. but being able to successfully trace and debug your application is a good start. When you say deadlocking are you using the async and await pattern? what is the environment , console, wpf, winforms, web app ect, core or framework. are using locks or semephores or mutexes

Comment: Are you literally using `Thread` objects or do you work with `Task`s? A bit of code would improve the question.

Comment: @Snoralx deadlocks mean your code locks or blocks in the first place. You can avoid locking altogether if you use eg Concurrent collections, async/await, the TPL Dataflow blocks.

Comment: You must use a debugger.  It isn't impossible to use a dead-man timer, but the only thing you can do is terminate the program.  Very rarely an acceptable solution.

Comment: @Snorlax  Visual Studio itself has several tools to make debugging easier. The `Parallel Stacks` debug window shows the call stack for all threads. Pause your application when you detect a deadlock and check what's going on. The Concurrency Visualizer addin shows which threads/tasks block each other. The IntelliTrace windows shows significant events while debugging

Comment: @Snorlax you'll have to post your code if you want specific help. Otherwise, *avoid* raw threads, global objects and shared state if you want to avoid deadlocks. Tasks, async/await, concurrent queues, pub/sub mechanisms like System.Threading.Channels provide better abstractions, lock-free operations and state isolation.

Comment: @Snorlax another option is to collect a crash dump, eg from production, and open it in Visual Studio. If you have the matching pdbs and source you can check the program's status as if you were debugging it.

Comment: @Snoralx yet another option is to [record IntelliTrace events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/intellitrace?view=vs-2017) in production and open the log in VS.

Comment: When you're running into deadlocks you have some serious design issues or errors somewhere in your code. So you should use a debugger and logging to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ideas here that come to mind that I'll outline.

## 1 Make Your Code More Robust

obviously, the easiest way to keep your thread healthy is to account for all these unhealthy states, if you're running into deadlocks use locks & semaphores more appropriately, debug why your deadlocks happen and find a way to account for these bad scenarios.

## 2 Agents & Error Handlers

Kind of related to above, if you can get to the point where you can correctly identify these issues without being able to fix them, you can put in place a system where the thread can know it's in a dangerous state and implement a system where that thread can say message the master thread, say that it's in a bad state, the master thread can then shut down the affected thread, spin up a new one from a set "safe state" and try to continue on from there. Multi-Process based languages like Elixir are very fond of this style of protection.

## 3 Logging/Polling

If there really is no way for you to tell what/how things are going on (there always is it's just sometimes too difficult) then the thread updating the shared resource on a set timeframe is a fairly simple thing to implement. Every minute have your thread update a float by exactly how long it has been since it last updated it, have your main thread check this float say every few minutes, (leave lots of space if your thread is too busy to update it on time). If say 5 minutes have gone by without an update then you can be fairly sure your thread is deadlocked. If you want to be able to see this after the fact then you can replicate these update messages to a log file too with the stack trace that time to see where it's getting stuck

## Conclusion

To conclude, if you can fix/reliably tell when an error/infected state is occurring, you can write code to account for those bad states, if you can't do that then your next goal should be getting to a point where you can do that.

Comment: This *comment* is so generic it could apply to any language without helping in any case. \

Comment: The question is so generic that it could apply to any language... This answer is better than most of the comments above because there must be some design issue or a major bug in the code. And using another LIB doesn't prevents you from running into deadlocks when you have such general issues.